# How to change a string from a user input to a integer in c#?

Tags: c#, integer, user-data

For my mini-project, I can't convert the string `.ReadLine` input to the integer needed for guessing
`int number = 5;`

```
  int user = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine);

  if (user == number){
    Console.WriteLine("You a Genius boe!!!");
  }
  else if ( user == (number - 1) ){
    Console.WriteLine("A bit Higher!");
  }
  else if ( user == (number + 1) ){
    Console.WriteLine("A bit Lower!");
  }
  else{
    Console.WriteLine("U Serious Bruh???");
  }
```

Comment: You faced with any special error ?!

Comment: Maybe because `ReadLine()` is a method (that returns a string), not a property? Possibly, use `int.TryParse()` to validate the input (because *Bruh* may not be *Serious*).

Answer (score 3):

I think you were nearly there with your code. All you needed was a loop to encapsulate the code asking the user to keep guessing.

```
    int guess = 5;

    while (true)
    {
        int user;
        Console.WriteLine("Guess a number boe???");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (Int32.TryParse(input, out user))
        {
            if (user == guess)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You a Genius boe!!!");
                Console.ReadLine();
                return;
            }
            else if (user == (guess - 1))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("A bit Higher!");
            }
            else if (user == (guess + 1))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("A bit Lower!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("U Serious Bruh???");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You didnt entered a correct value try again!!!");
        }
    }
```

As pointed out Console.ReadLine() is a method, you were missing the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
     bool Valid = false;
    int Number;
    while(Valid == false){
      string Input = Console.Readline();
      if(int.TryParse(Input, out Number){
        Valid = true;
  if (Number == number){
    Console.WriteLine("You a Genius boe!!!");
  }
  else if ( Number == (number - 1) ){
    Console.WriteLine("A bit Higher!");
  }
  else if ( Number == (number + 1) ){
    Console.WriteLine("A bit Lower!");
  }
  else{
    Console.WriteLine("U Serious Bruh???");
  }
      }
      else{
        Console.Writeline("Not an integer, please try again.")
      }
    }
```